# Create list of Folders within Android app directory

Tags: android, arraylist, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception, hashmap

I want to list each folder that is located within the app directory. 
So far I can scan the directory and list each folder that has been created and log each folder, which is stored in the app directory to the console.

I first check to see if the user folder exists. If it doesn’t it will create it then it sets the variable “homeDir” to the Userfolder.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> groupsList;

File homeDir;

private void isUserFolderExist() {

    File m_applicationDir = new File(this.getFilesDir() + "");
    File Userfolder = new File(m_applicationDir + "/" + uid);
    homeDir = Userfolder;
    //File directory = getDir(uid, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    //Log.v("creating", uid + " Folder");

    if (!Userfolder.exists()) {
        Userfolder.mkdir();
    } else{
        //Log.v("Directory", "exists");
    }

}
```

I have then tried to create an ArrayList of each folder found in the directory. By using the code below within an AsyncTask. I have followed a few tutorials, which show how to create a list of information from a json file, and I have tried to apply the same method.

```
    class folders extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        try {

            File directory = homeDir;

            File[] files = directory.listFiles();

            for(int i = 0; i < files.length;i++){

                String dirId = Integer.toString(i);
                String name = files[i].getName();

                HashMap<String, String> groups = new HashMap<String, String>();

                groups.put("dirId", dirId);
                groups.put("name", name);

                groupsList.add(groups);

            }
        }catch (NullPointerException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        MainActivity.this, groupsList,
                        R.layout.list_item, new String[] { "dirId", "name"}, new int[] {
                                R.id.dirId, R.id.name});

                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

I come across a NullPointerException when it gets to groupsList.add(groups);

```
    04-01 16:10:12.273: W/System.err(336): java.lang.NullPointerException
    04-01 16:10:12.593: W/System.err(336):  at com.example.folder.MainActivity$folders.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:433)
    04-01 16:10:12.683: W/System.err(336):  at com.example.folder.MainActivity$folders.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
    04-01 16:10:12.723: W/System.err(336):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
    04-01 16:10:12.733: W/System.err(336):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
    04-01 16:10:12.733: W/System.err(336):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
    04-01 16:10:12.733: W/System.err(336):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
    04-01 16:10:12.733: W/System.err(336):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
    04-01 16:10:12.733: W/System.err(336):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

I haven't had any luck in finding why this is happening.

Is it because I am trying to do it within an AsyncTask?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have **not initialized your list**. So, without initializing if you are trying to work around with an object it will end you up in Null pointer exception.

Try to initialize your ArrayList before for loop..

```
groupsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

Comment: Sorry I missed that one line. I had initialized groupList with the following
`ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> groupsList;`

Comment: That's Right sir. Hi @hariharan sir am sethu from Villupuram. I did ma UG in KCT.

Comment: @woody1990 that's only declarition not initialization. you have to initialize like my ans

Comment: @Hariharan Thanks very much. You were right. I thought I had initialised it.

I changed the line 
`ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> groupsList;`
to
` ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> groupsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();`

Which fixed it.

Comment: @hariharan sir actually i saw you that's why am simply send ma msg to you sir.

Comment: @Sethu where did you see me?

Comment: @Hariharan sir actually i did ma UG in KCT.. where you did sir.. you came to ma college a??